# lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

i am trying to make a program which calculates the geometrical average.But i get this error mesage: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

---

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>

int main() {
    float number1,number2,avarage;
    printf("enter the numbers which you want to calculate geometrical average of them > ");
    scanf("%f %f",&number1,&number2);

    average*average=number1*number1+number2*number2;

    printf("Geometrical avarage is:%f",sayi);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

---

(I tried "==" operator too but 0.00 assigned to average at these time)

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect the effect of assigning a value to `average*average` to be? It's nonsensical. BTW: What type is `average`, only finding the definition of `avarage`. Is that really your code?

Comment: What you are expecting from `average * average`? It doesn't contain any value.

Comment: I don't know if that wackiness is even legal in Haskell... (average * average) = 4... what would the value of average be... -2 perhaps ?

Comment: i am sorry for the confusion.when i was trying to translate my sentences into english,i wrote wrong formula for geometrical average and variable name.i understood main reason my mistake. thanks for your supports

Answer (score 1):

It is rather a mathematical problem than a programming problem.
If you know that

`average*average = number1*number1+number2*number2`

you must evaluate average first. Solution is

`average = sqrt(number1*number1+number2*number2)`

EDIT1:
but geometric mean should be computed as

`average = sqrt(number1 * number2)`

according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula to calculate Geometric average:

`Geometric average = square root of (number1 * number2)`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{

    float number1,number2,average;

    printf("enter the numbers which you want to calculate geometrical average of them > ");
    scanf("%f %f",&number1,&number2);

    average=sqrt(number1*number2);

    printf("Geometrical average is:%f",average);

    return 0;
}
```